# WiredTiger logs password in cleartext when hashing them in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, wiredtiger

i implemented my user authentication including the password hashing in mongoose inside a pre-save-hook (see article https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1).

Everything works fine, but i discovered a security problem: WiredTiger logs before the hook is executed and therefore i get a log file on the server which includes the password as cleartext.

I enabled file encryption (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/) but that does not completely solve this problem as root users and so on still have access.

Is there a possibility to solve this?

Regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Solution was actually quite simple: Instead of doing the hashing in the "pre save", i'll do it now in the "pre validate" and WiredTiger logs the hashed password.